# How to make XAML grid height/width adjujst of its contains (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im trying do [this](https://i.stack.imgu) sizeable form from windows forms.
I am using Grid because stack dont resize its controls.
But my grid rows [dont want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnJ0z.png) to stretch down.

I have no idea how to force them to.

I found some wrong solutions like margin or Height.

Any help welcome!

My code:

```
<Window x:Class="Diploma.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Diploma"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="LightCyan"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 10 10 10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                Записи
            </Label>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="20"></TextBox>
                
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="60">
                    Поиск
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            
            <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></ListBox>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" MaxHeight="20">
                Загрузить
            </Button>

        </Grid>
        <!--<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ShowsPreview="False" Width="3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Check `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>` in [How to create a complex Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-complex-grid)

Comment: @emoacht thanks for the answer!
Sadly Auto width/height makes grid column/row and its control minimum of size.
Now my controls compressed at the top. But actually my textbox havent maximum size, he should stretch.

Comment: Updated: i made what i want using `*` for cell i want to be maximized and `Auto` to minimized. Im not sure its acceptable approach, but it works!

Comment: It is virtually same as the `<RowDefinition/>` commented as `<!-- This row will receive all remaining Height -->` in that page.

Comment: If you want extra spacing around elements you can adjust the Margin and Padding properties

Answer (score 0):

To make the grid adjust its height and width based on its contents, you can set the Width and Height properties of the top-level Grid to Auto, as so:

```
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Auto height/width helps a bit, but it force cells be as low as they can. I want only my textbox be stretchable and fill all extra space.
[This is what i tell about](https://i.ibb.co/y5WJYGk/temp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid (as you did), but in your case, instead of height and width, you set "margin=0" so that the elements take up all the space around.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD0jD.png

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1">
        Поиск
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an Auto so that it take all the remaining space or you can specify it in "*" ath the end which act like a "%".